# xaml image not displayed during runtime but displaying during design (VB, wpf) - why?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm trying to understand WPF and have created a WPF test project. I've put a *monkey01.jpg* image in every folder starting from the project's root, moving up in hierarchy, to the *debug* folder. On the `MainWindow` I've created an `Image` and defined the **source property** to point to the *monkey01.jpg* and it displays correctly in **design view**. But when I run it, the image doesn't appear.

- If I add the image file to the **project** as a **resource**, it will be displayed during runtime which is expected. (But this is not what I'm testing here)
- If in the **xaml** file I write the **absolute path** as in `Source="C:\Users\User\Desktop\visual_studio_projects\WpfApplication1\monkey01.jpg` it will be displayed too.
- But if I use a **relative path** (like in the example below), the image won't be displayed. It's as if upon execution, the program doesn't run inside the project folder and its subfolders; Instead it runs in some other location that has no access the image. Why this behaviour? What am I missing?

This is the `MainWindow.xaml` code:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="Thumbnailtest" Source="monkey01.jpg" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not even sure this is a xaml behaviour or something related to visual studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Copy to Output Directory` in the Properties Window for the image to "Copy if newer".

Comment: Thank you Postlagerkarte! - While it's not what I've been trying to understand, it's definitely a useful thing to keep in mind - I can already think of a few scenarios where this could be a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here when I've set the image to Resource and don't copy, note I changed your monkey image to .png and I created a folder for it(Data/Images).

```
<Window x:Class="MasoneryLibrary.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasoneryLibrary;assembly=MasoneryLibrary"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="Data/Images/monkey01.png" HorizontalAlignment="left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" Height="456"  Margin="285,0,-58,-136" Stretch="None" StretchDirection="DownOnly"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Hmmmm.. is this a library? **You should use [URI packs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) to be safe**.

With URI pack:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MasoneryLibrary;component/Data/Images/monkey01.png" HorizontalAlignment="left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" Height="456"  Margin="285,0,-58,-136" Stretch="None" StretchDirection="DownOnly"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: Thank you Stian for your pointings - I'm sorry if I've mislead you, the *Masonry Library* reference was merely a remnant - I've edited the code to be more to the point and added some clarifications to the question too!

Comment: <Grid><Image Source="pack://application:,,,/YOURAPPLICATION;component/monkey01.jpg"/></Grid> or your example at the top there, works just fine here in 2013. Image is set to resource and not copy. I'm coding C#. Which version of vs are you using? The editor is rather buggy. Any third party things that can cause issues? Any codebehind? I honestly don't know, it should work just fine. So it's all speculation :)

Comment: Once again, thank you Stian; I'm using VS2013 (Express) and the example is selfcontained - just open VS, create new wpf project and paste the xaml code overwritting the existing xaml code. But the trick is *not* to set the image as a resource - I mean, if I set it as a resource it works okay; but my question is related to *what happens if I don't* set it as a resource: Then, it works with absolute paths, but not relative paths and this is what is bugging me!