# show image in tabcontrol tab header if textbox has text WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

Okay, What I'm trying to accomplish:

A tabheader which gets an image if the textbox inside has text. but if the textbox inside the TabItem doesn't have any text, then the image should not be shown.

this is what I have so far:

----- TAB ITEM CODE -----

```
            <TabItem Name="tabAantekeningen"  Header="">
                <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="8" Text="Aantekeningen"/>
                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="..\Resources\validate.png" Height="20" Width="17"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <TextBox Name="txtOmschrijving" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>
            </TabItem>
```

----- TAB ITEM CODE -----

----- Code Behind -----

```
    public void SetTabItemHeader()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOmschrijving.Text))
        {
            tabAantekeningen.Header = "Aantekeningen";
        }
    }
```

----- Code Behind -----

IS there a way that I can say: txtOmschrijving.Text == Empty so hide the Image?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Didn't see your seccond question there, yes there is use a **[IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)**, where you check if the string is empty and Bind To Visibility for instance, so you return Visbility.Collapsed when empty or else Visbility.Visible.
Like this :

```
public class StringEmptyToVisbililityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == null) || !(value is string) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Fully working xaml, change your namespaces and URI pack**

```
<Window x:Class="TabItemHeader.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabItemHeader"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringEmptyToVisbililityConverter x:Key="StringEmptyToVisbililityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>        
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Name="tabAantekeningen">
            <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="8" Text="{Binding Path='Header',RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"/>
                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="pack://application:,,,/TabItemHeader;component/Resources/Images/validate.png" Height="20" Width="17" Visibility="{Binding Path='Header', Converter={StaticResource StringEmptyToVisbililityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <TextBox Name="txtOmschrijving" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

This will bind to the listboxitem which wraps everything in a listbox. The converter will only show this image when the string is not empty. You can do alot of fun with them :)

**[WPF cheat sheet is a really handy and compact paper on all types of bindings.](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf)**

Oh..I am assuming this image will be deployed with your application? Then please ensure that your image is set to resource, you should consider using [uri packs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) as well for your images, an [example is in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25618352/2285592) as well as the xaml provided. If your image is dynamic, you will have to bind them to some model in an observablecollection. 
Tip: I'll stop pushing this to far, but you should consider having a look at the MVVM pattern. I just used code behind my self, so the answer wouldn't get to big. It's whole other topic! =) There are also cleaner ways to either share templates, and change them on types bound in the collection.

Hope it helps.

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: It doesn't work mate.... IT's weird because VS says it can't find the "Converter={StaticResource StringEmptyToVisbililityConverter}"... you know whats wrong?

Comment: @RaZor you have to add that converter to your project, check your namespaces. If you are using R# just remove the local:String... and let it fix it for you, or verify that you have the correct namespace. Runs here...[Here is an image of the output](http://i.imgur.com/SmxHwbO.png), in the designer you see there is no text and image. When you run the application, I set some text in the code, and voila your picture appears

Comment: Lol, I forgot the reference in the Window.Resources..... But now I did that. The image is not shown when the txtOmschrijving.Text != string.Empty....

Comment: @RaZor it's impossible for me to tell what you are doing wrong. I wrote 7 unittests to validate the converter, and as I've stated earlier. It works all well here. Since you are using codebehind. I hope you are not setting the text in the ctor? WPF loads it's views async, so it's generally not safe to mess around here(Try the [Loaded event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742302(v=vs.110).aspx) or override [OnApplyTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) or something). That's all I can think of...

Comment: @RaZor have you debugged the converter and checked the output? Have you changed the URI pack to fit your application's assembly name?

Comment: Debug no. Will try now, Change uri? Yep.

Comment: When I debug the Convert method, I used 2 ways. 1 way object value is filled. but the other way it's empty... Could you send me a copy of your test project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60964/discussion-between-stian-and-razor).